# Jira API GET all users from Jira project with specific status

Tags: ruby, rest, jira, jira-rest-api

In my Ruby app I'm trying to get all agent users from my service desk board. It means all users with `status: 'ServiceDesk'`. Is it possible using only base auth?

In curl I was trying something like:

```
curl -D -u USERNAME:PASSWORD -X GET -H "Content-Type: application/json" https://company_name.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/user/assignable/search?project=SERVICEDESK
```

But all what I get is an error:

> Warning: The file name argument '-u' looks like a flag.
>   curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL
>   {"errorMessages":["Internal server error"],"errors":{}}%

Is there any way to get those data with basic auth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there's an issue with the curl command, try this

```
curl -D- -u USERNAME:PASSWORD  https://company_name.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/user/assignable/search?project=SERVICEDESK
```

[image: It worked with me]

Comment: what `-D-` do actually ?

Comment: I think -D- and -D are no different. The issue is happening because of the Header: "Content-Type:application-json" this header doesn't work with GET method